# Create a section index and jump to page menu from a string

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string containing the section titles and page counts per section as follows:

```
    string = "section1;section2;section3;section4|2 3 1 4"
```

i would like to be able to create a section index and use the titles as links to the appropriate pages in the whole document.

any suggestions? My initial thought was to split the string into the section headers and page counts, then split these and append the titles to a unordered list?  That would take care of the section titles but what about the page counts?

```
    var options = string.split('|');

    var sections = options[0];

    var section_titles = sections.split(';');

    for (a=0;a<section_titles.length;a++){
    $('ul').append('<li><div class="title">'+sections[a]+'</div></li>');
    };

    var counts = options[1];

    var section_counts = counts.split(' ');

    ???????
```

Please send your suggestions.

Comment: I re-read the question a few times can't seem to understand what you want to do next. Also I think `a<sections.length` should be `a<section_titles.length`...

Comment: Sorry for the confussion, basically I have an app that merges and rasterizes pdf documents into one file.  however i want to use the documents that the app uses to create a table of contents for the merged single file it uses these to create.  I know the document title and the page counts of each but can't figure out a way to list them as a table of content so the user can click on the title and go to that page in the document.  Does this make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what ended up working for me...

- I changed the string to include "title;count" seperated by a |
- I am outputing this as an unordered list

> ```
> var str = "section1;2|section2;3|section3;1|section4:4"
> var d = 0;
> var ul = $('<ul>');
> var sec = toc.split('|');
> var a = 0;
>   for (a = 0; a < sec.length; a++) {
> var secArr = sec[a].split(';');
>   var sectiontitle = secArr[0];
>   var sectioncount = secArr[1] * 1;
> var jump = d;
> d = d + sectioncount;
>   if (sectiontitle == ''){
>   } else {
>   $('#sections').find('ul').append('<li><div class="toc"><div     class="title">'+sectiontitle+'</div></div><span class="jumper"
> style="display:none;">'+jump+'</span></li>');
>   }
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**If your application is a web application and you are not trying to create an index IN a pdf document, this will help.**

Simplest way is to make use of anchors and links.

**Read these please:**
[link](http://www.bignosebird.com/tags/ahref.shtml)
[anchor](http://www.html-5-tutorial.com/a-tag.htm)

Then see full code example bellow. You can copy all of it in a test.html file, then open it in your browser to see how it behaves.

```
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("\<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'>\<\/script>");
</script>
<style>
section{font-size:100px;}
</style>


First things first, your data setup seems odd. If you can change that string's setup, try going the JSON way. For example:
<script>
var jsonString = '{ "section1":2, "section2":3, "section3":1, "section4":4 }';

var objectFromJson = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString);
var ul = $('<ul>'); 
for (var prop in objectFromJson)
{
    var li = $("<li>");
    var divTitle = $("<div>");
    divTitle.addClass("title");
    var titleLink = $("<a>");
    titleLink.text(prop);
    titleLink.attr("href","#" + prop + "/" + objectFromJson[prop])
    divTitle.append(titleLink)
    li.append(divTitle);
    ul.append(li);
    }
$("body").append(ul);
</script>

If that is not possible, let's continue on what you have
<script>
var str = "section1;section2;section3;section4|2 3 1 4"
var options = str.split('|');

var sections = options[0];
var numbers = options[1];

var section_titles = sections.split(';');
var numbersArr = numbers.split(' ');

var ul = $('<ul>'); 
for (var a=0; a < section_titles.length; a++)
{
    if(numbersArr.length > a)
    {
        var li = $("<li>");
        var divTitle = $("<div>");
        var titleLink = $("<a>");
        titleLink.text(section_titles[a]);
        titleLink.attr("href","#" + section_titles[a] + "/" + numbersArr[a])

        divTitle.addClass("title");
        divTitle.append(titleLink)
        li.append(divTitle);
        ul.append(li);
    }
    }
$("body").append(ul);
</script>


<section>
<a name="section1/2">section1</a><br/><br/>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam at tristique est. Curabitur rhoncus consequat sagittis. Proin pharetra elit nec turpis rutrum a lobortis nisi ornare. Nulla nec nisl diam, vel semper orci. Phasellus iaculis nibh a velit pulvinar sagittis eu ut massa. Cras vestibulum, urna sed ultrices consequat, purus leo venenatis lorem, a bibendum nibh eros ut leo. Curabitur viverra urna id ante mattis ultrices. Nulla et velit enim, vel condimentum magna. Vestibulum ullamcorper consectetur porta. Maecenas eget dui nec turpis condimentum aliquet in in risus.
</section>

<section>
<a name="section2/3">section2</a><br/><br/>
Ut ac blandit nisi. Phasellus fringilla, est vel hendrerit mollis, dui sem sagittis justo, eget fermentum odio ipsum at sem. Sed tempor, nibh eu vulputate vehicula, lectus neque eleifend erat, at tincidunt orci dui a tellus. Vestibulum viverra urna in tellus vestibulum semper. Etiam volutpat sodales rutrum. Morbi elementum, lacus ut fermentum malesuada, ipsum sem viverra arcu, ut consequat libero dui et arcu. Cras ut libero nulla, nec rhoncus erat. Integer id enim id nulla sagittis congue. Integer mollis tempor viverra. Ut non nisi sem, et semper lacus. Vivamus turpis mi, hendrerit non pellentesque a, iaculis id nibh. Pellentesque nec arcu magna, at posuere eros. Duis eu quam at nulla porttitor aliquet. Vestibulum cursus mattis purus, a sodales mi rhoncus vitae. Phasellus quis urna nec orci rhoncus consequat.
</section>

<section>
<a name="section3/1">section3</a><br/><br/>
Donec pellentesque congue sollicitudin. Fusce aliquam, velit et cursus iaculis, nisl massa vulputate magna, vitae imperdiet felis tortor sit amet purus. Vivamus aliquet laoreet ligula quis aliquet. Vivamus fringilla purus ut lorem faucibus viverra. Sed accumsan tincidunt tempus. Donec id velit in dolor luctus gravida. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean sit amet nulla augue. Proin vel tincidunt est. Curabitur imperdiet elementum suscipit. Praesent dignissim magna eget sapien pretium vestibulum id at arcu. Integer egestas purus non.
</section>

<section>
<a name="section4/4">section4</a><br/><br/>
Donec pellentesque congue sollicitudin. Fusce aliquam, velit et cursus iaculis, nisl massa vulputate magna, vitae imperdiet felis tortor sit amet purus. Vivamus aliquet laoreet ligula quis aliquet. Vivamus fringilla purus ut lorem faucibus viverra. Sed accumsan tincidunt tempus. Donec id velit in dolor luctus gravida. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean sit amet nulla augue. Proin vel tincidunt est. Curabitur imperdiet elementum suscipit. Praesent dignissim magna eget sapien pretium vestibulum id at arcu. Integer egestas purus non.
</section>


</body>
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the quick reply.  I am rasterizing the pdf into jpg images to be viewed using jquery cycle slider.  I need to be able to go to the page number of the section in the cycle slider, so I don't think the anchors will work.  I think I need to somehow get the pagenumber of the start of the section out of the total page count for the cycle slider.